# Is there a way to append file and keep the columns names in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to add one row in top of my data.table while i am exporting it to csv!

```
library(data.table)
cat("Source Date: 01/01/2020\n", file = "dt.csv")
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5)
fwrite(dt, "dt.csv", append =TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But add col.names=TRUE in the fwrite function:

```
library(data.table)
cat("Source Date: 01/01/2020\n", file = "dt.csv")
dt = data.table(a = 1:5)
fwrite(dt, "dt.csv", append = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

If you want to read this file you need to skip the first "Source Date..." row:

```
> fread("dt.csv", skip = 1, header=TRUE)
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
```